# Sympy: How can I store an equation in order to solve it later numerically?

Tags: python, sympy, solver

Hello wonderful people,

I am building a physics model for some project. I have found a nice equation for my interest variable, but I would like to be able to solve the problem repeatedly with different parameters. What I would like to do is to save my equation as an object in a file (using pickle for example), then loading it at runtime and feed it the parameters it needs.
How would you achieve this?

With a simple example, the whole process would look like this:

(in a jupyter notebook)

```
import sympy as sp
import pickle

a, b, c = symbols("a b c")
eqn = sp.Eq(b + c, a) #for a real equation I would simplify it before using sympy
with open("eqn.txt") as f:
    pickle.dump(eqn, f)
```

and then later in the app's code:

```
...
with open("eqn.txt") as f:
    eqn = pickle.load(f)
b = 1
c = 2
#magic line to put b and c into the equation
a = sp.solve(eqn, a)
print(a) # 3
```

Implementing the whole equation directly in a function is probably not an option although I am considering how to implement it manually. It just looks really, really hard to do and if I could do it in two lines using simpy, that'd be great.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: What is your equation ?

Comment: Does `subs` do what you want?

Comment: I did try subs but I couldn't make it work like that

Comment: And the equation is for some model we are developing so I'm not quite sure I'm authorized to share it, sorry ^^ I guess that would be convenient indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
with open("eqn.txt") as f:
    eqn = pickle.load(f)
b, c = 1, 2  # b,c are python symbols here
reps = dict(zip(symbols('b c'), (b, c)))  # keys are SymPy Symbols, values are 1,2
eqn = eqn.xreplace(reps) #magic line to put b and c into the equation
a = sp.solve(eqn, a)
print(a) # 3
```

It is important to keep in mind the distinction between `b = 1` and `b = Symbol('b')`. The left hand side of the expressions are Python variables and on the right, an int or a SymPy Symbol, respectively. In a SymPy expression you might reference a Python variable and its *value* will be included in the equation:

```py
>>> from sympy import *
>>> b = 1
>>> b + 1
2
>>> b = Symbol('b')
>>> b + 1
b + 1
>>> eq = _
>>> eq.subs(b,1)
2
>>> b=2  # assigning a new value to b does not change the object in eq
>>> eq
b + 1
>>> eq.subs(b, 2)  # i.e., eq.subs(2,2) doesn't work -- no 2 in eq
b + 1
>>> eq.subs(Symbol('b'), 2)  # replace the Symbol with value of 2 works
3
```

So in `reps` above, zipping the symbols to their corresponding values creates a mapping that can be used to do the replacement.

There is more discussion of such issues in the documentation `gotchas` file, but this should help with your current issue.

Comment: Thank you for the very complete answer! this does the trick for the simple case, I should be able to implement it for the real thing.

Comment: Aaaaaand it worked! You are the king of kings my dear sir! Many thanks